# Want to convert list of dictionaries into columns of list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries `lst` having same two keys each having different values in every dictionaries. I want them in form of single dictionary `dict`
where both keys has all its values into a list. Keeping in mind, keys are to be taken from variables `dimLst` and `metricLst` and they are unknown otherwise.. Any ideas?

```
lst = [
    {'Location': 'ANNEX', 'ToTal_Dwell': 60.0},
    {'Location': 'CHENNAI', 'ToTal_Dwell': 86.0},
    {'Location': 'DADRI', 'ToTal_Dwell': 108.0},
    {'Location': 'JNPT', 'ToTal_Dwell': 39.0},
    {'Location': 'KOLKATA', 'ToTal_Dwell': 67.0},
    {'Location': 'MUNDRA', 'ToTal_Dwell': 82.0}
]

dimLst = ['Location']
metricsLst = ['ToTal_Dwell']
```

I am expecting output to be like:

```
dict = {
    'Location': 
        ['ANNEX', 'CHENNAI', 'DADRI', 'JNPT', 'KOLKATA', 'MUNDRA'],
    'ToTal_Dwell': 
        [60.0, 86.0, 108.0, 39.0, 67.0, 82.0]
}
```

Comment: I think if you initialise a new dict with the keys in `dimLst` and `metricsLst` you can just iterate over `lst` and and append each value to your dict's keys

Comment: You should add some code that shows what you have tried - what's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [d[k] for d in lst] for k in lst[0]}
{'Location': ['ANNEX', 'CHENNAI', 'DADRI', 'JNPT', 'KOLKATA', 'MUNDRA'], 'ToTal_Dwell': [60.0, 86.0, 108.0, 39.0, 67.0, 82.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution besides dictionary comprehension

```
lst = [
    {'Location': 'ANNEX', 'ToTal_Dwell': 60.0},
    {'Location': 'CHENNAI', 'ToTal_Dwell': 86.0},
    {'Location': 'DADRI', 'ToTal_Dwell': 108.0},
    {'Location': 'JNPT', 'ToTal_Dwell': 39.0},
    {'Location': 'KOLKATA', 'ToTal_Dwell': 67.0},
    {'Location': 'MUNDRA', 'ToTal_Dwell': 82.0}
]

locationList = []
dwellList = []
locDict = {}

for i in lst:
    locationList.append(i['Location'])
    dwellList.append(i['ToTal_Dwell'])

locDict['Location'] = locationList
locDict['ToTal_Dwell'] = dwellList
print(locDict)
```